What is mem::take doing in Write::write for slice &mut [u8]?
While researching how to overwrite a part of a slice of bytes ([u8]), I noticed the following implementation of Write::write in the stdlib of Rust. (See also the sources at GitHub.)
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
impl Write for &mut [u8] {
    #[inline]
    fn write(&mut self, data: &[u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        let amt = cmp::min(data.len(), self.len());
        let (a, b) = mem::take(self).split_at_mut(amt);
        a.copy_from_slice(&data[..amt]);
        *self = b;
        Ok(amt)
    }
    ...
}

According to the documentation, this function is supposed to write the given data into the self. However, I don't understand how this function works.
let (a, b) = mem::take(self).split_at_mut(amt);

My understanding is that mem::take should return a copy of the content of self. It should also replace the content of self with an empty slice, what ever that means, but that is not relevant right now. Afterwards, this copy is split into two parts, a and b.
a.copy_from_slice(&data[..amt]);

This is the only line where we actually use the given data. However, we are only copying it into a, which itself is just part of a copy. Afterwards, a is never used again. How does the content of data end up in self?
*self = b;

I am also not sure what this last statement is doing, but it dosen't seem to do anything with our incoming data. If I would ignore the documentation and function name, I would intuitivly expect the following result from the implementation:
fn main() {
    use std::io::Write;
    let mut buffer = String::from("abcdefg");
    let _ = unsafe { buffer.as_bytes_mut().write(b"xyz") };
    println!("{:?}", buffer);
    // Intuitive expectation: "defdefg"
    // Actual result:         "xyzdefg"
}

The actual result matches what I have expected based on function name and documentation, but not based on the function implementation. What am I missing?

Note that Self is a &mut [u8] so the receiver self has the type &mut &mut [u8]  (double mutable reference)

@cafce25 After seeing your comment, I think part of what caused my confusion is that &mut [u8] is not a mutable reference of [u8], but a different construct as the &mut in front of other types. Or in other words, the whole &mut [u8] is the slice, not just the [u8]. I knew that &mut in front of [u8] makes the content of the slice modifiable, not the slice itself, which I think led me to the unconscious bias that you cannot have a (mutable) references to a slice, which is obviously wrong. (It would probably also cause various contradictions with the rest of my knowledge.)

That's ever so slightly wrong [u8] is a slice, but commonly we say slice when we really mean a slice reference (& [u8]) because slices need indirection. So &mut [u8] really is a mutable reference to a slice of bytes [u8].

@cafce25 Ok, makes sense. References to slices are still a different thing than "normal" references. And the meaning of a slice is encoded in these special references. Anyway, thanks for highlighting the wrong nomenclature. That slices are not the references, but the area of memory pointed to, makes absolute sense. When looking at it this way, the syntax is also more relatable. :D

It's important to remember that a slice in Rust doesn't contain any data, it references data. A slice is just a pointer to the start of some data and the length of that data.
Secondly, the write method on slices also "updates the slice to point to the yet unwritten part":
fn main() {
    use std::io::Write;
    let mut buffer = String::from("abcdefg");
    let mut bytes = unsafe { buffer.as_bytes_mut() };
    let _ = bytes.write(b"xyz");
    println!("{:?}", bytes); // b"defg"
}

That's what the *self = b does. b is the unwritten part of the slice and we assign that to *self. In order to be able to do that, we need mem::take:
Without lifetime elision, the method looks like this:
impl<'slice> Write for &'slice mut [u8] {
    #[inline]
    fn write<'this>(&'this mut self, data: &[u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        let amt = cmp::min(data.len(), self.len());
        let (a, b) = mem::take(self).split_at_mut(amt);
        a.copy_from_slice(&data[..amt]);
        *self = b;
        Ok(amt)
    }
    ...
}

So the type Self is &'slice mut [u8] (because that's the subject of the impl block), meaning the type &'this mut Self (i.e. the type of self) is &'this mut &'slice mut [u8]. That means that in order to assign to *self we need data that outlives 'slice, the outer lifetime. But because self is behind a references that only outlives 'this, we can only get a dereference to data that outlives 'this from it. And because split_at_mut has the signature split_at_mut<'a>(&'a mut self) -> (&'a mut T, &'a mut T), it would only give us slices that outlive 'this when called on self (because the lifetimes of the two subslices are tied to the lifetime of the input).
We need to get the &'slice mut [u8] out of the &'this mut &'slice mut [u8] and that's exactly what mem::take does. It has the (simplified) signature take<T>(&mut T) -> T, so in our case take<&'slice mut [u8]>(&mut &'slice mut [u8]) -> &'slice mut [u8]. It does that by leaving a default replacement in its stead (an empty slice in this case, which is just a pointer that may or may not dangle and the length 0).
Now a and b both reference data that outlives 'slice and we're free to assign b to *self.

Do I understand you correctly that mem::take is effectively only copying the reference (i.e. the slice), but not the content? And on the same note, that *self = b is also only overwriting the slice? I know that slices are references, but my error was that I did not realize or consider that you can have a (mutable) reference to a slice (which is a reference by itself). But of course you can, thanks for your answer.

Essentially, yes. The bytes the slice references don't move at any point during this whole procedure. take just moves the slice out of the mutable reference it's behind.
